# TFS Interface like Codeplex?

Tags: tfs, codeplex

Quick question, are there any interfaces that can utilise TFS, but provide a UI similar to CodePlex, i.e. browse change sets, provide an overview page, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) (WinClient, not web based)

Comment: Thanks. I've seen SideKicks before, but not really keen on the UI, plus it provides a bit too much info - really all I want is an overview.